# Spanish phrasal verbs

Tags: gramática, verbos, preposiciones, terminología

## Español

La característica más difícil del idioma inglés (al menos en mi caso particular) son los "*Phrasal verbs*".

Hoy me encontré una oración en un periódico que me hizo pensar sobre la existencia de *Phrasal verbs* también en español. Si comparamos las dos oraciones siguientes:

> Facebook **saldrá a** la bolsa.
>   Facebook **saldrá de** la bolsa.

Se tienen significados distintos, a pesar del hecho de que se usa el mismo verbo.

¿Es materia de investigación en la lengua española una característica como ésta, denominable "Verbos con preposición en español"? O, al menos, ¿es un tema de estudio utilizado para enseñar español a hablantes de inglés?

---

## English

The most difficult feature of English language  (at least for myself) are "Phrasal verbs".

Today I stumbled upon one sentence from a newspaper that made think about Phrasal verbs in Spanish. If we compare these two sentences:

> *Facebook **saldrá a** la bolsa*.  (it will get into the stock market).
>   *Facebook **saldrá de** la bolsa*. (it will get out the stock market).

we get different meanings, despite the fact the same verb is used.

Is such a feature called "Spanish phrasal verbs" a matter of research within Spanish language, or at least a topic used when teaching Spanish to English speakers?

Comment: No hay que ver los phrasal verbs como algo más complicado, simplemente hay que aprenderse esas combinaciones, del mismo modo que te aprendes las palabras sueltas. Y a la larga vas viendo patrones generales que simplifican las cosas. Por ejemplo go in, get in, come in y en general los verbos de movimiento con in indican hacia adentro.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The examples you wrote about are not phrasal verbs. I don't think there is such a thing as phrasal verbs in Spanish.

They are verbs that sometimes change their meaning totally. For example, the verb "*to take*" means that you grab something with your hands and you lift it up (an example). The verb "*to take after*" doesn't mean that you grab later, or at least not as you might intend it literally. It means "*to resemble (a parent or ancestor)*", such as in the sentence:

> *You took after your mother.*

The verb you used in your examples, "*salir*" is just a verb plus prepositions.

Some expressions that might be considered "phrasal verbs", like "**tener que**" that means "to have to", but that instead are called **perífrasis verbales** are the following:

1. "list element" **+ Infinitive**:

   Ir a, pensar, tratar de, venir a, darle (a uno) por, echar(se) a, empezar (comenzar – *más formal*) a, estar a punto de, meterse a, ponerse a, romper a, acabar de, acabar por, dejar de, llegar a, deber, haber (3<sup>rd</sup> person) + que, haber de, tener que, deber de, volver al, estar para, estar por, pasar a, quedar en.

   > Example: *Estoy por irme* (estar por + ir)
2. "list element" **+ verb in -ing form**:

   andar, estar, ir, llevar, quedarse, seguir, continuar, venir, verse.

   > *Example*: *Sigo escuchando esa canción.* (seguir + escuchar)
3. "list element" **+ past participle**:

   andar, dar por, dejar, estar, ir, venir, llevar, quedar.

   > *Example*: *Llevamos explicadas 10 lecciones.* (llevar + explicar)

Answer (score -1):

El español no tiene *phrasal verbs*, pero en Chile sí tenemos y son propios nuestro (por ejemplo, *echar abajo* (take down)) y es separable de igual manera. Otro ejemplo es *tomar por encima* (take over) que tambien es separable.

Todo dependerá del país en que se encuentre. Sin embargo, el ejemplo "Facebook saldra un la bolsa" tiene un error ortográfico terrible. Esa frase no existe de esa forma, pero sí se puede implementar de otra forma como por ejemplo "saldrá un nuevo accionista en Facebook".

Como sea, el español no tiene *phrasal verbs* excepto el de Chile que tiene por millones al igual que el inglés y son oficiales nuestros, de ningún otro país.

Comment: Solo se conocen como dichos coloquiales. El concepto aplicado a la enseñanza no existe así en Chile.