# What's the best way to say "perífrasis verbal" in English?

Tags: traducción, terminología

***"Perífrasis verbal"*** seems to be used pretty consistently at least in some references to refer to grammatical constructions like *ir a*.

But I'm not sure if it's a set grammatical or linguistic term, and I'm not sure if there's one best way to say it in English or if it depends on the particular use:

- compound verb
- verbal phrase

**Is there a best English equivalent of "perífrasis verbal"?**

Here's an example as it's been posted in [an answer right here on our site](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/473/75):

> Si el infinitivo o el gerundio forman parte de una **perífrasis verbal**, en la mayor parte de los casos los clíticos pueden colocarse también delante del verbo auxiliar de la perífrasis, que es el que aparece en forma personal:

And [another](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/337/revisions) which has since been edited:

> **Perífrasis verbal** "ir a" is roughly the same as "going to" in English: we primarily use it when talking about the immediate future.

Comment: Just to add to the "mess" :D, there's also [my answer](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/705/76) for the question "[Spanish phrasal verbs](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/704/spanish-phrasal-verbs)" which is about them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the grammatical term is actually **periphrasis**. Compound verbs and verb phrases both refer to different things.

I came to this conclusion after viewing the [translation on WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=per%C3%ADfrasis) and [the English Wikipedia article for *periphrasis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periphrasis).

Comment: I'd add "verbal" to your "periphrasis" there to be more specific. :) But I'm curious to see if other people have more to add.

Comment: Are you implying "verbal" in the Spanish meant "related to words" rather than "related to words" and as such it can be omitted, leaving only "periphrasis"?

Comment: I've seen that used, but not referring to "words", rather to "verbs"... Is that the correct adjective in English? Maybe it's ambiguous for that...

Comment: Periphrasis in English, according to Wikipedia, relates specifically to verbs already. I don't think a `verbal` modifier is needed.

Comment: Sorry my comment should read: `Are you implying "verbal" in the Spanish meant "related to words" rather than "related to verbs" and as such it can be omitted, leaving only "periphrasis"?`

Comment: @KevinK. In fact the Wikipedia article specifically includes examples of periphrasis with adjectives too (using "more" to form the comparative in English).

Comment: @hippietrail This is true. `Verb periphrasis` might be clearest. I modeled that after `verb phrase`.